# Prove that addition preserves order. (for natural numbers)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, peano-axioms

Prove that addition preserves order.  $a ≥ b$ if and only if $a+c ≥ b+c$.
(using peano axioms)
I try to do it by induction on $c$. Can I use $(a+c)++ ≥ (b+c)++$. I am not sure because first we will have to prove that if $a\geq b$ then $a++\geq b++$ how do I do that ?

Comment: I guess $x++:=x+1$, isn't it?

Comment: yes. you're right. it is also represented as S(a).

Comment: If I recall correctly, when formally facing statements related to the elementary properties of the order of $\Bbb N$, typically you define $[a,\infty)$ as the intersection of all $S$-saturated subsets of $\Bbb N$ which contain $a$ and say that $a\le b\iff b\in [a,\infty)$. In doing so, one has to deal with some "unexpected" technical lemmas. One of which is the following: "if $[a,\infty)=\Bbb N$, then $a=0$". If memory serves me right, you need to prove it when you show that "$b\in[a,\infty)$" is transitive. Can it be taken as a given?

Comment: I require a proof without the use of set theory.

Comment: Then, provide the definition of "$\le$".

Comment: Let $n$ and
$m$ be natural numbers. We say that $n$ is greater than or equal to
$m$, and write $n \geq m$ or $m \leq  n$, iff we have $n = m + a$ for some
natural number $a$. We say that $n$ is strictly greater than $m$, and
write $n > m$ or $m < n$, iff $n \geq m$ and $n \neq m$.

Comment: I wonder how I could forget that one...

Answer (score 1):

The step you have trouble with (namely, the case $c=1$) amounts to the fact that the sum is commutative.

If $b\le a$, then there exists $d$ such that $a=b+d$.

Hence $a+1=(b+d)+1=(b+1)+d$.

Once you have case $c=1$, you can indeed use it for the other inductive steps.

*Observation:* You can do the proof above for a general $c$, actually, and spare yourself the induction.