# Proving addition preserves order in natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, peano-axioms

I have the following question:
Prove $a≥b$ if and only if $a+c≥b+c$ $\forall$ natural numbers. (using Peano Axioms)

The solution I checked is different from what I used and same applies to the ones I saw here ([Proof that addition preserves order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708039/proof-that-addition-preserves-order) and [Prove that addition preserves order. (for natural numbers)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833316/prove-that-addition-preserves-order-for-natural-numbers) and some more)

I did the following:

Assuming this isn't true, then we have $a≥b$ and $a+c<b+c$

By cancellation law we get $a<b$ in the the second statement, which contradicts the first, end of proof.

Note: Cancellation law was stated in the book for $a+c=b+c$ but I think I can use is this way as well.

Alternative way I thought about to avoid not using the cancellation **exactly** as stated:

Assuming the statement isn't true then we have $a \geq b$ AND $b+c>a+c$. Thus, we have $b+c=a+c+k$ where $k$ is a positive ($>0$) natural number.
This statement can be simplified to $b=a+k$ according to the cancellation law.

Plugging this in our main equation we get $a+k \geq a$ which is always wrong since we have $k>0$, thus we have a contradiction, end of proof.

Is my solution correct? If not, what's the flaw in it?

Comment: I think it's hard to give a proof or verify your proof without knowing exactly what axioms you are starting with.

Comment: @MaximGilula Peano Axioms, I will update the post, thank you

Comment: You can actually use cancellation also for inequalities because they reduce to equalities by definition. In your case, $a+c<b+c$ is equivalent to $\exists ! h \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}:\ (a+c) + h = (b+c)$, which is an equality; therefore by (addition properties and) cancellation you get $\exists ! h \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}:\ a + h = b$, i.e. $a<b$.